# Magento 2.1 Rest API - Adding to Extension Attributes for VI/Orders/?searchcriteria

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, extension-attributes

I have some custom data that I gather on checkout. Using etc/extension_attributes.xml, I was able to add this data to the extension_attributes output on VI/Order/#id, but when I use VI/Order?searchcriteria api calls, the data is not in the extension attribute output.

Any ideas why it doesn't show up both places?  Here's my etc/extension_attribute.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="tdv_customfield" type="anyType"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface">
        <attribute code="tdv_customfield" type="anyType"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="tdv_customfield" type="anyType" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236756/9169