# Magento2 add custom attributes to Rest API index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria

Tags: magento2, rest-api

In my custom extension, I added custom attributes to api `index.php/rest/V1/orders/:id` and it works like in this documentation [dev docs](https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-get-value-of-custom-attribute-on-magento-2-rest-api/)

But attribute does not show in api for orders list `index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria...`

How can I add attributes to orders list ?

Comment: Hello! Were you able to resolve your issue, if yes then please post the solution as it is haunting me for a while now.

Comment: @omelandr please accept the answer if correct

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it with the help of plugin. I had to add an attribute delivery_type in order and order collection api response. Here is how I have added it through my module.

**etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_type" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**etc/webapi_rest/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="orderInformationUpdate" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Api\OrderRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/Api/OrderRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;


class OrderRepository
{

    const DELIVERY_TYPE = 'delivery_type';

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     *
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $deliveryType = $order->getData(self::DELIVERY_TYPE);
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryType($deliveryType);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $deliveryType = $order->getData(self::DELIVERY_TYPE);
            $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryType($deliveryType);
            $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```